# calculate a single jaccard coefficient between two sets of terms in R

Tags: r

I am doing text mining by R. I have two sets or terms: terms1: chr[1:523] and terms2: chr[1:44]. terms1 and terms2 are terms of two lsa space. terms1 is calculated from several text files but terms2 is calculated from one text file. I want to compare this two sets of terms by finding jaccard similarity. which function and corresponding code I can use ?please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
jaccard_i <- function(t1, t2){
  tw1 <- unlist(strsplit(t1, " "))
  tw2 <- unlist(strsplit(t2, " "))
  i <- length(intersect(t1, t2))
  u <- length(union(tw1, t2))
  list(i=i, u=u, j=i/u)
}

jaccard_i(terms1, terms2)
```